# Jboss server error : Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war"

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jbpm

When starting the jboss server, it giving an error Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war". But when i'm running jbpm6 demo using start.demo its working fine.

```
23:43:41,042 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "jbpm-console.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:447) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:273)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageDrivenBeanMetaData(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:244)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processBeanMetaData(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:88)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processBeanMetaData(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:65)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.processDeploymentDescriptor(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:143)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:84)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more

23:43:41,104 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
23:43:41,104 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "jbpm-console.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"jbpm-console.war\""}}
23:43:41,104 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 49681ms - Started 344 of 423 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
23:43:41,104 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "dashboard-builder.war" was rolled back with no failure message
```

Answer (score 17):

try staring jboss with ./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml or any other alternative that allows you to start with the full profile

Comment: I agree with this answer, but just a side note - don't forget that standalone-full.xml will not have jbpm datasource configured out of the box.

Comment: @salaboy, Thanks.. I got frustated with this error for many hours, googled and found to add <mdb>..</mdb> in standalone-full.xml and not running that file while server starting.. but finally i run successfully... Thanks again...

Answer (score 11):

Best solution: Goto jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments folder and delete all existing files....

Run again your problem will be solved

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem, found that I was missing

```
<mdb>  
  <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>  
  <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>  
</mdb>
```

under

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
```

in standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

Comment: Could you explain this more? What do any of these tags do... what do any of these names mean?

Answer (score 2):

1. delete your project folder under `C:\....\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments\YOUR-PROJEKT-FOLDER`
2. restart your wildfly-server

Answer (score 1):

you should run standlone.bat or .sh with -c standalone-full.xml  switch 
may be work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, my error was:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.RESTful_Services_CRUD.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

I use `jboss` and `glassfish` so I changed the `web.xml` to the following:

```
<servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
```

Instead of:

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Intellij Idea you can click services tab and select artifacts. Then you can click add all and ok.